# why do some functions in the List structure require the "List" prefix and some do not?

Tags: sml, smlnj

(I am using SML/NJ)

The list structure http://sml-family.org/Basis/list.html includes
@, hd, tl, null, concat, etc.

Some of them are available without a prefix: @, hd, tl, [], concat.
But others, such as exists, and nth require the List prefix. see below:

```
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.79 [built: Tue Aug  8 23:21:20 2017]
- op @;
val it = fn : 'a list * 'a list -> 'a list
- concat;
val it = fn : string list -> string
- nth;
stdIn:3.1-3.4 Error: unbound variable or constructor: nth
- exists;
stdIn:1.2-2.1 Error: unbound variable or constructor: exists
- List.nth;
[autoloading]
[library $SMLNJ-BASIS/basis.cm is stable]
[library $SMLNJ-BASIS/(basis.cm):basis-common.cm is stable]
[autoloading done]
val it = fn : 'a list * int -> 'a
- List.exists;
val it = fn : ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> bool
```

Why? I tried to find an answer in the "Definition of Standard ML (1997)"
but I could not find anything related to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some names are available unqualified because they are also bound in the *top-level environment* of the SML Basis library, including the ones you listed. See [here](http://sml-family.org/Basis/top-level-chapter.html) for a complete list.

Comment: I don't see how this really answers the question "Why?". OP already knows that some list functions have been made available to be used in an unqualified way and some haven't. Your "because" might address *how* it is done but not *why* it is done.

Comment: @JohnColeman, since the OP mentioned that he had searched for an answer in the language definition, I assume his "why" is to be interpreted as "why does this work", as in: where is it spec'ed. But maybe he can clarify. (The boring rationale simply is convenience for the most common cases.)

Comment: I see what you mean. The link that you give explicitly addresses the "why" question. I interpreted it as the question *why* the language was designed in such a way that some list functions can be used right out of the box but some need to be used in the List structure.